# Creating a matrix CSV file with numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matrix

Relatively new to python here.

So I have a CSV file with contents like this:

```
 dsa dds fsdf dasdsa
 1 1 32.2 9 4
 1 2 53.2 8 2
 1 3 44.2 0 1
 1 4 12.3 3 2
 1 5 15.6 4 3
 2 1 12.3 3 2
 2 2 91.3 4 11
 2 3 32.3 5 33 
 2 4 44.2 3 2
 2 5 55.2 4 1
 3 1 60.2 4 2
 3 2 80.2 1 15
 3 3 10.2 4 1
 3 4 99.2 8 3
 3 5 13.1 10 2
 4 1 32.3 19 2
 4 2 10.3 12 3  
 4 3 52.3 22 4
 .  .  .   .  .
 .  .   .  .  .
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
    1    2     3    4  .  .  .
1 32.2  53.2  44.2  12.3  .  .
2 12.3  91.3  32.3  44.2  .  .
3 60.2  80.2  10.2  99.2  .  .
4 32.3  10.3  52.3   .    .  .
.   .    .      .    .    .  .
.   .    .      .    .    .  .
```

As you can see, i'm only using the first 3 columns of the csv file and I skipped the first row (rubbish data).

I'd like to use numpy to do this, so I thought this code would do the trick:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import numpy as np

l, c, v = np.load('test.csv', skiprows=1, delimiter=',').T[:3,:]
m = coo_matrix((v, (l-1, c-1)), shape=(l.max(), c.max()))
print(m.toarray())
```

This works, however the first 2 columns in the CSV file are excluded from the output. The result turns out to be:

```
[32.2  53.2  44.2  12.3
 12.3  91.3  32.3  44.2
 60.2  80.2  10.2  99.2
 32.3  10.3  52.3    .]
```

Any thoughts on how I can generate the matrix I need (the output)?
The CSV file is huge (it's got around 10k rows and columns), but just need to use the first 3 columns.

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
data2 = data['dds'].reshape(len(data['dds'])/5, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=range(1, 6), index=range(1, data2.shape[0]+1))
print(df)
```

**update:**

without 'rubbish data':

```
import pandas as pd
names_ = range(1, 6)
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=names_)
data2 = data[3].reshape(len(data[3])/5, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=names_, index=range(1, data2.shape[0]+1))
print(df)
```

Comment: What'd happen to the code if no 'rubbish' data was present?

Comment: Just installing pandas, I have anaconda 3.5 but my python version is 3.4.4. Is there a difference?